# How to forward iterator calls to a class's private member?

Tags: c++

I have a class like,

```
class A {
public:
    // .. public methods
private:
    std::list<int> m_list;
};
```

I would like for the `begin()` and `end()` operator to correctly work for `A`. So that `A.begin(), B.end() == m_list.begin(), m_list.end()`.  What's the best way to "forward" all appropriate iterator calls to the `m_list` member? The goal is for all STL algorithms to work "as expected" for my class A, as though it was really a list.

Comment: Are you avoiding `A.m_list.begin()` ? that would be the easy way

Comment: @Ivan Not really; `m_list` is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tempting to inherit from `std::list<int>` rather than composing it, to achieve this.

I know people say "don't inherit from standard containers" as a general rule and they're usually talking about the lack of a virtual destructor, a rationale which doesn't really come into play here because you're not likely to be storing `std::list<int>*`s pointing to your `A` (right? I mean, you're clearly not doing so currently!).

However, even that "edge case" falls apart on Windows when you want to export `A`; you end up exporting the whole bloomin' standard library and all hell breaks loose.

This brings us back to… "don't inherit from standard containers".

---

What then?

Aliases and member functions. :D

You can often get away with implementing just the following:

```
begin()
cbegin()

end()
cend()

rbegin()
crbegin()

rend()
crend()
```

and forwarding them directly to `m_list`, e.g.

```
auto begin() { return m_list.begin(); }
auto begin() const { return m_list.begin(); }
auto cbegin() const { return m_list.cbegin(); }
```

You may also wish to define some member types, matching [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Iterators)'s, for full drop-in compatibility. It depends what you need to do. Personally I'd just add forwarding things as and when you need them. You'll probably find yourself needing to define at least the `iterator` aliases though.

Answer (score 2):

You can also inherit privately from the type. Private inheritance is just like composition, but lets you forward member functions easily:

```
struct A : private std::list<int> {
    // make some members public
    using std::list<int>::begin;
    using std::list<int>::end;
    using std::list<int>::cbegin;
    using std::list<int>::cend;
    using std::list<int>::rbegin;
    using std::list<int>::rend;
    using std::list<int>::crbegin;
    using std::list<int>::crend;

private:
    auto m_list() const& noexcept -> std::list<int> const& { return *this; }
    auto m_list() & noexcept -> std::list<int>& { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: Does this have the problem Lightness Races BY-SA 3.0 mentions on windows about inadvertently exporting the whole stdlib if A is exported?

Comment: I don't know what he talks about. Maybe DLLs? I'm not aware of any obvious traps using private inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is often the greatest:

```
class A {
public:
    // .. public methods

    using iterator = std::list<int>::iterator;

    iterator begin() {
      return m_list.begin();
    }

    iterator begin() const {
      return m_list.begin();
    }

    iterator end() {
      return m_list.end();
    }

    iterator end() const {
      return m_list.end();
    }
private:
    std::list<int> m_list;
};
```

Of course, you also have to implement the `const_iterator` equivalent if you wish, and also the reverse iterator methods `rbegin()` and `rend()`

Comment: or just `auto` ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am going to take this approach.